# Why does c++ program crash after temporary object is destroyed at end of scope

Tags: c++, pointers, temporary-objects

So i'm a little bit confused. This bit of code will fail when trying to printList() after changeList() is called. But, when I REMOVE the destructor, the code runs without crashing. My question is, why? I understand that in the bit of code I have here, im passing the object by value to changeList so therefore, a temporary object is created as a copy of the parameter. Any changes made to this temp object do not affect the original object I passed in. So why does the program crash as if I was accessing a destroyed object? Shouldn't the temp object be destroyed after changeList is done and then printList should just print 1 thru 10 instead of 1 thru 45.

```
void printList(Node*);
void changeList(LinkedList);

int main(){

    LinkedList list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        list.append(new Node(i+1, nullptr));

    changeList(list);
    printList(list.getHead());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void changeList(LinkedList list){
    list.append(new Node(45, nullptr));
}

void printList(Node* head){
    Node* temp = head;
    if (temp != nullptr){
        cout << temp->value << endl;
        printList(temp->next);
    }//end if
}
```

Comment: Changelist makes a copy of the list - I guess this is not what you want

Comment: It makes no sense to call an external program "pause". Use Ctrl-F5 to run your program from Visual Studio and keep the console window open. Your code doesn’t expose problems, probsbly there 's trouble with the class definition you didn't show.

Comment: Where is your destructor code?

Comment: Here's a wild guess. You haven't defined a copy constructor. So the copy constructor called passing arguments to `changeList()` copies the list head. When that temporary is destroyed, it destroys all the nodes because they are shared. You don't realise this because the node sharing means `append` has the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume correctly the destructor of the `LinkedList` will destroy all the nodes in the list. I also assume that the copy constructor makes a shallow copy of the list. (If you did not implement a copy constructor explicitly, this is the default.) And this happens when you run the code:

```
void printList(Node*);
void changeList(LinkedList);

int main(){

    LinkedList list; //first instance is created

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        list.append(new Node(i+1, nullptr)); // nodes added to the first instance

    changeList(list); // copy constructor called, second instance is 
                      // created with the same set of node objects


    printList(list.getHead()); // nodes does not exist any more because of
                               // the destructor called at the end of changeList


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void changeList(LinkedList list)  // copy constructor called, second instance is created
    list.append(new Node(45, nullptr));  // nodes added to the same chain of nodes
} // destructor is called, all the nodes are destroyed

void printList(Node* head){
    Node* temp = head;
    if (temp != nullptr){
        cout << temp->value << endl;
        printList(temp->next);
    }//end if
}
```

You can fix thi problem by accepting a reference parameter in the `changeList` function:

```
void changeList(LinkedList &list)  // no copy
    list.append(new Node(45, nullptr));  
} // no destructor is called
```

Comment: So changeList makes a temporary list of nodes with the same pointers as the original nodes I have? So then it's not a copy...no? ChangeList took my list, made its own list object and then used the same node pointers I used in my original?

Comment: So When an object is passed by "value," it's pointers aren't "copied" as well? I wouldve expected new pointers to be allocated and the values in the origin pointers to be copied into the new pointers.

Comment: This depends on your `LinkedList` implementation, but if you did nod program it explicitly to do so, then it will not duplicate your node objects. Pointer will be copied of course, but in the case of a tipical linked list implementation that meens that the contained head pointer is copied only, and it still points to the same node object. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) Wikipedia article about shallow and deep copy.